# Java adding to the front of queue - deque

Tags: java, queue, deque

this is my first question here and I hope everyone is well.  I had to code an array implementation of a deque or a double ended queue but was having some trouble understanding the enqueue element to the front method, I got it to work by fiddling around a bit but I am still having a hard time understanding the logic:

```
void addAtFront(E)
{
    if ( front == 0 )
        front = array.length - 1;
    else 
        front = ( front - 1 ) % array.length;

    array [front] = element;

    count++;
}
```

Can someone explain what is happening in the if statement here?  if front is 0 then we are adding an element all the way at the end of the array?  Wouldn't that be the same as enqueing at the rear?

Comment: You should learn how a d-bugger works it will show you exacly how the code works and whats happening.

Comment: @HelloWorld, the amount of questions that get asked on this site that can be sovled simply by debugging their own code is staggering

Comment: Thank you, I just watched a video on it, eclipse has a really good debugger I never knew about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using what is called a circular array to store this double ended queue. Essentially, your logic works in such a way that the array you use for storing the queue loops around at the end and returns to the beginning, and the same the other way around.

[image]

When you need to add an element to the front of your queue, you need to expand it to the left, but when you're at the beginning of your actual array implementation (a.k.a when the front index is zero), it is already as far to the left as it can get. The solution is to loop around to the end, pretending the array is a big circle.

The reason you can logically do that is because your array and your queue are not effectively the same; the array merely contains your queue. You use the front and back variables as a way of keeping track of where you can find your queue's elements in the array. That means that the last element of the array is not necessarily the last element in your queue. Your queue can traverse and grow along the array as much as it wants. The only limit the array imposes on your queue is the size; the array obviously cannot hold a queue that is larger than it.

All this being said, you should have similar looping logic for adding an element to the back of the queue. I'm guessing you already do based on this::

```
else 
    front = ( front - 1 ) % array.length;
```

I assume your `addAtBack` method has this line:

```
back = (back + 1) % array.length;
```

That modulus operation handles the looping for you. If the back goes past the end of the array (a.k.a. the back is array.length), the modulus will set the back index to 0, looping it to the beginning of the array. Unfortunately, that modulus operation doesn't work as effectively the other way around, hence why you need that if statement only for adding to the front. You should be able to remove that modulus operation from your `addAtFront` method and replace the line with `front--;`.

Comment: Thank you sir, that was extremely helpful and intuitive.